# How to separate input data from the input field "street address" of gravity forms?

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

How to separate input data from the input field "street address" of gravity forms?
For example, to transform

```
123 Main St, Buffalo, NY 14203, the USA
```

into

```
{ 
  street: 123 main st, 
  city: Buffalo, 
  ZIP: 14203, 
  country: USA
}
```

Comment: "https://www.webuyuglyhouses.com/" like this website top menu search bar does. top menu search bar will be visible when you scroll down

Comment: This is an example of a bad question. You must provide coded examples of your attempts, a detailed description of your issue, your current input, and a detailed description of your desired output. See [How to Ask a Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)